# Using SaltStack to append to lines in a file if a regex is found

Tags: regex, sed, salt-stack

In essence, I'm trying to convert this sed command to a Salt file.replace method:

```
sed -i '/^\s*kernel/ s/$/ elevator=noop/' /etc/grub.conf
```

What it does, is if it finds a line in grub.conf that begins with any number of whitespaces and then "kernel", it replaces that with the entire original line + elevator=noop at the end.

so this:

`kernel vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 [...] KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet`

becomes:

`kernel vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 [...] KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet elevator=noop`

But when I directly copy in the sed cmd into pattern and repl in Salt's file.replace, I get this line:

`s/$/ elevator=noop vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 [...] KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not proficient in `sed` and couldn't fully understand your `sed` command, but one thing I noticed that you may have missed is that `sed` uses `$` for referencing groups while Python regex uses `\` for that.

That aside, your description was clear. So:

If on the minion I did:

```
echo "kernel vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 [...] KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet" > /tmp/foo
```

Then on the master:

```
salt '*' file.replace /tmp/foo '(\s*kernel.*)' '\1 elevator=noop'
```

Result:

```
--- 
+++ 
@@ -1 +1 @@
-kernel vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 [...] KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
+kernel vmlinuz-2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 [...] KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet elevator=noop
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using regex for this, is there any reason you can't manage the file with salt?

What salt does is houses a copy of the file. You can then make changes to the file on salt and once you run the state against that specific server it will update with the changes made on the salt side. The link below should give more depth.

http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html

Comment: Sometimes managing the whole file on the salt master is simply overkill, esp. when you only want to make a small change on a file such as grub config that could also get autogenerated on the minion with kernel upgrades. Forcing people to copy each and every such copy into salt config in order to normalize it could easily be considered inane.